# Category that returns array of uicolors

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have the following category extension of `UIColor`:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Colors)
- (NSArray *)reds;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "UIColor+Colors.h"

@implementation UIColor (Colors)

- (NSArray *)reds {
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:98.0/255.0 alpha:1],[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0f green:37.0f/255.0f blue:75.0f/255.0f alpha:1],[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:52.0/255.0 alpha:1],[UIColor colorWithRed:90.0/255.0 green:13.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1],[UIColor colorWithRed:53.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1], nil];
}

@end
```

Then in a viewcontroller, I'm trying to do something like this: `[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor reds][0]];` Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What problem are you seeing? You could clean up the code by using modern objective C syntax BTW `@[...]`, instead of `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: ...]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most likely problem is that the function `reds` needs to be a class method for you to be able to call `reds` on the class. So something like this:

.h

```
@interface UIColor (Colors)
   +(NSArray *)reds;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation UIColor (Colors)

+(NSArray *)reds {
    return @[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:98.0/255.0 alpha:1],
             [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0f green:37.0f/255.0f blue:75.0f/255.0f alpha:1],
             [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:52.0/255.0 alpha:1],
             [UIColor colorWithRed:90.0/255.0 green:13.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1],
             [UIColor colorWithRed:53.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
}

@end
```

So basically a `+` instead of a `-`. If you use `-` it is an instance method so you'd have to instantiate an instance of UIColor to call `reds`.

Comment: Minor nitpick - it's a "class method", not a "static class method".

Comment: Fixed. Cut my teeth on C++ ;)

Comment: @Ron thanks Ron for commenting on the syntax. My actual problem was just that I hadn't imported it. Whoops.

Comment: Side note: this recreates the array (and the colors) every time the method is called. It might be better to stick the array in a `static` local variable the first time and return that instead.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, you want to create a class method (method who's definition starts with "+") not an instance method.

However, your code is pretty pointless, since you create and return a new array of UIColor objects every time the class method is called.

That's your only real option in a category since categories can't add instance variables or global variables. You might be able to use associative storage, but I'm not sure how you'd use associative storage from a class method.

Comment: What should I do instead then?

Comment: Fetch the array in viewDidLoad into a scoped NSArray pointer, NSArray *reds = [UIcolor reds];  and then use that one array multiple times to skin all your UI. [button1 setBackgroundColor:] etc etc. otherwise you're creating 5 instances of UIColor (and an NSArray) everytime you need a colour..

Comment: If necessary, you can associate an object to the class object the same way you would an instance. Also, the file that defines a category can certainly contain global (or file-scoped) variables, or the category could use method-scoped `static`s. Those have nothing to do with the class or the category, anyways.